# How remove specified some word from txt file using regex?

Tags: regex

In my txt file available some extra word so if in the line available any extra word then I need remove full line for this file.

Example

```
stackoverfolow ?

overflow 

sadrian 

kamrul #

alex @
```

like this 5 line I want remove 3line where available `? # @`.

Any good idea how can I am solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php then this may work

```
preg_replace('/(.*[?#@])/g', '', $yourtext);
```

If you're using javascript then try this

```
var str = "text";
str.replace(/(.*[?#@])/g,"");
```

Comment: I am using for this txt file where available some extra data.

Comment: if in my txt file available any searching ward then going remove from full line.

Comment: I am using windows form application for remove txt file specified data.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're using. You're asking for full code, but you need to understand that code is different depending on the programming language. Tell me what language you're programming on. Windows form application is it c#? Microsoft Visual Studio?